# New Django App MEDIA_URL pathing incorrect

Tags: python, django

So, I've created a new app in Django via `python manage.py startapp foo`

My new app will not load any files in the `/site_media/` directory, via the `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`. They are attempting to path from the App's directory, not the `/site_media/` directory.

---

**Example:** 
Instead of loading from `http://sitename/site_media/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css`

it tries to load from `http://sitename/foo/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css`

---

Here is a snippet from the `settings.py` which defines the `MEDIA_URL`

```
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
```

I can force the files to load correctly in the app by replacing `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` with `/site_media/` in the `base.html` and my `show_foo.html`, but this then breaks the pathing on the rest of the site.

I'm not sure what else anyone would like to see to try and diagnose the issue, but I'm stumped!

---

Just in case:
from `urls.py` in my app directory

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('foo_web.foo_track.views',   
url('^$','view_foo_track',name='foo_home'),  
url('^newentry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)$','write_form_data',name='foo_track_new'),
)
```

---

`settings.py` edit*removed comments for readability

```
import os
current_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from os import sys, path
sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
import run_server

cherry_config,django_config = run_server.get_web_server_parameters()
DEBUG = django_config['DEBUG']
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = django_config['TEMPLATE_DEBUG']
CACHE_MODE = django_config['CACHE_MODE']
DB = django_config['DB']
HOST = django_config['HOST']


LOGIN_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': '%s' % DB,             
        'USER': 'postgres', 
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '%s' % HOST,
        'PORT': '5432',              
    }
}

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': CACHE_MODE,
        'LOCATION': 'my_cache_table',
        'TIMEOUT': 1800,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 10000
        }
    }
}

ADMINS = (
    ('**', '**'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

#~ EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '**' 
SERVER_EMAIL = '**' 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = "**"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "**"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "**"

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

#~ gettext = lambda s: s
#~ LANGUAGES = (
    #~ ('de', gettext('German')),
    #~ ('en', gettext('English')),
#~ )

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = current_dir + '/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'

STATIC_ROOT = current_dir + '/media/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/site_static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = '***'

if DEBUG:
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
    )    
else:
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        )),
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
    )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'sensei_web.middleware.FilterPersistMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #~ 'sensei_web.middleware.ProfileMiddleware'

    #~ 'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    #~ 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #~ 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sensei_web.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sensei_web.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    current_dir + '/templates',

)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'foo.foo',
    'foo.foo',
    #~ 'foo.foo',
    'foo.foo',
    'foo.foo',
    'foo',
   'foo.foo',
   'foo.foo_track',
    )

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `django.core.context_processors.media` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings?

Comment: Hmm. I have no `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` and plead ignorance as I did not configure the site at all. Finally something to "blame" on my co-worker, lol. So I should add the block outlined here([ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS]) and should get some constructive error messages?

Comment: @shuttle87 I tried adding the block you spoke of, and nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help! It turns out this is just a mistake I made :( Very interesting consequences though.

I noticed something funny in the logs about `A (% csrf_token %) was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value. This is uaually caused by not using RequestContext.`

Lo and behold, in my `views.py` this line was incorrect:
`return render_to_response('foo_track/foo_track_show.html',{'access':access})`

it should have had the `RequestContext(request)` as well like this:
`return render_to_response('foo_track/foo_track_show.html',{'access':access},RequestContext(request))`

And now everything works. Sheesh!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to explicitly define a "site_media" url in your urls.py

Like so:

Add this to imports

```
from django.conf import settings
```

And this to your urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Otherwise, Django will assume you are using a different web server to serve the static content. Which, by the way, is a great idea. Here is an article on [serving static content with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we are looking to transition to Apache in the near future. I found my error, just another case of me messing things up!